# PagePiling.js determine if elements are in view

Tags: javascript, pagepiling.js

I'm attempting to animate some text when they come into view. Things work fine but when I introduce pagepiling.js, my function for determining if my elements are in view returns false. Here is the function:

```
function elementInViewport(el) {
    var top    = el.offsetTop;
    var left   = el.offsetLeft;
    var width  = el.offsetWidth;
    var height = el.offsetHeight;

    while (el.offsetParent) {
        el = el.offsetParent;
        top += el.offsetTop;
        left += el.offsetLeft;
    }

    return (
        top < (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight) &&
        left < (window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth) &&
        (top + height) > window.pageYOffset &&
        (left + width) > window.pageXOffset
    );
}
```

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check how to use of the [pagePiling.js callbacks](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js#callbacks) for that such as `afterLoad` and `onLeave`.

You can also check [the available example](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js/blob/master/examples/callbacks.html) within the `examples` folder of the github repo.

Answer (score -1):

This function should work:

```
function isInView(el) {
  let bb = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return bb.top <= window.innerHeight && bb.bottom >= 0
    && bb.left <= window.innerWidth && bb.right >= 0;
}
```

Here is a demo:

```js
document.onscroll = function() {
  document.querySelector('.status').textContent = isInView(document.querySelector('.element')) ? 'IN' : 'OUT';
}

function isInView(el) {
  let bb = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return bb.top <= window.innerHeight && bb.bottom >= 0
    && bb.left <= window.innerWidth && bb.right >= 0;
}
```

```css
.before,
.element,
.after {
  height: 200vh;
  background: wheat;
}
.element {
  background: teal;
}
.status {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  padding: 1em;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="before">Before</div>
<div class="element">Element</div>
<div class="after">After</div>
<div class="status">...</div>
```